# Different authorities for user JWTs vs. client_credentials JWTs

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-identity-platform

I have noticed that when I obtain a JWT from Azure AD after logging on, the JWT specifies "https://login.microsoftonline.com" as the issuing authority.  However, if I obtain a JWT using the client_credentials flow, the issuing authority is "https://sts.windows.net".  Having dissimilar issuing authorities makes it difficult to configure an application to consume both kinds of JWTs, since the configuration process only allows you to specify a single authority.

Is there a reason why Microsoft uses different issuing authorities for JWTs?  I assumed that it was because MSFT wants to segregate the two usage scenarios.  That is, they want to discourage the creation of applications that switch between user-based and non-based security contexts.  Is there some other reason I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

The changes in format of Issuer Authority value for the token that you're observing are most likely due to the different versions of token i.e. Azure AD v1.0 token or Azure AD v2.0 token (and probably not because you used client credentials flow or say auth code flow for acquiring access token for same application)

Azure AD v2.0 token - issuer format

```
    https://login.microsoftonline.com/<Azure AD Tenant GUID>/v2.0
```

Azure AD v1.0 token - issuer format

```
    https://sts.windows.net/<Azure AD Tenant GUID>/
```

Please look at this Microsoft Documentation - [Access Tokens Reference - Sample Tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#sample-tokens)

Notice this one has issuer format for each of the sample tokens there.

Also take a look at the important note in the same Microsoft Documentation Link shared.

As the documentation says, tokens are created based on the 'audience'. It also gives an example of using `accessTokenAcceptedVersion`.

[image]

You mention that even though you're using Azure AD v2 endpoint to acquire token with client credentials flow, you're seeing issuer as per v1 format.

I think that **the application that you are acquiring the token for is important** here, and if it accepts v1 token, then you will get back v1 token (even though you used v2 endpoint).

Also, if possible please share decoded tokens (minus sensitive info) in your question for more clarity.

Comment: What application are you acquiring the token for? If it's your application and you have access to manifest, try checking the `accessTokenAcceptedVersion` in your app registration > manifest. It might be that the application expects a v1 token and that's why it's being issued a v1 token.. Also, the user token that you mentioned in your question which had issuer like `login.microsoftonline.com/..`, was that token for the same application or something different?

Comment: So your claim is that the changes to Issue Authority are due to the token endpoint that constructed the JWT, and furthermore you say that an issuer value of 
    sts.windows.net/<Azure AD Tenant GUID> 

means the token was issued by an AD v.10 endpoint. However, I am explicitly calling the following URL to get the client_credentials token: login.microsoftonline.com/<Azure AD Tenant GUID>/oauth2/v2.0/token 

That's a V2 endpoint. So if I understand you correctly, I shouldn't see a V1 Issuer in the token. What am I missing?

Comment: The manifest is as follows:
 "accessTokenAcceptedVersion": null.

And yes, both tokens are for the same app.  I'm trying to determine if it is possible to set up an ASP.NET Core API that responds to User tokens AND client_credentials tokens without a lot of configuration.

Comment: Could you please share both the decoded tokens (you can use https://jwt.ms or https://jwt.io) ? Also.. plz hide/remove any sensitive info.. To answer your broader question, you API responding to different tokens.. yes that's possible.. in one case you'll have user context and other case it will be application identity (no user)

Comment: @G.A.Alderman I've added a screenshot of an important note from Microsoft documentation and also a probable reason for what you're seeing in terms of token endpoint used to acquire token v/s the issuer value. Once you share decoded tokens the reasoning for difference between two tokens (one from user flow v/s client credentials flow) might also become clearer.